# Does UNION overwrite previous results?`

Tags: mysql

I have two queries on the same table and I need to get results which do not appear in the first resultset.

There are several ways to get there (I do not ask for one), my first try was this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT
        o.custom_order_id AS 'order',
        'yes'      AS 'test'
    FROM orders
    WHERE <first criteria>

    UNION

    SELECT
        o.custom_order_id AS 'order',
        'no'      AS 'test'
    FROM orders
    WHERE <second criteria>
) x
WHERE x.test = 'no'
```

`UNION` does not append rows which already appeared in the first resultset.

Actually I do get rows like

```
12345    no
```

but `12345` does appear in the first resultset (query before `UNION`).

Why that ?

**Edit:**

`custom_order_id` has no index and is not primary key (although it actually is unique) - does `UNION` need a (unique) index or pk to recognize a row as *already-in-first-resultset*?

Comment: `UNION` will return unique **rows**. `12345 yes` and `12345 no` are **two unique rows**. In your example if you remove `test` field you'll get what you want.

Comment: Can someone tell me what's wrong with my answer? The downvote confused the crap out of me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNION` uses the entire tuple to determine if a row is unique. In your case that is (order, test).

As one half of your answers has test set to "yes", and one "no", you can end up with multiple orders with the same id (one for yes, one for no).

Comment: I was so focused on the order id that I totally failed to vision my test flag lawl :-) Thank you and Adriano.

Answer (score 0):

You only get rows with "no", because that's what you specified in your `WHERE` clause at the end:

```
WHERE x.test = 'no'
```

Eliminate that and `UNION` will return **unique rows** from unioned queries.

`UNION` doesn't necesarrly need keys, although optimizing query is almost always a good idea :) Try running `EXPLAIN ( above query with UNION goes here)` and see what is produced.

Comment: Not me downvoting (I generally do not downvote answers on my own questions), but I think it's because the WHERE is not the problem here :-)

Comment: So I just mistunderstood the question. Thx.